# How do I install lzip/plzip?

Tags: windows-7, linux, installation, compression

A former developer backed up all of our files using plzip. We no longer have the server he used to compress them and have not been able to find a program to decompress these files. We have Windows 7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux machines. It doesn't really matter which but can somebody tell me how to install lzip or plzip? The files are here http://www.nongnu.org/lzip/ but I have no idea what to do with them. Nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: For the heck of it, see if 7-zip can deal with it.

Comment: It can't. That's the first thing I tried. Maybe there's some version that does but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These will run on a Red Hat machine, you need to compile them.

Download http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/lzip/lunzip-1.3.tar.gz

Put it in the same dir as your files. (backup the files somewhere)

From the command prompt run

```
gunzip lunzip-1.3.tar.gz
cd lunzip-1.3
./configure
make
sudo make install # <-- this command to install the program, this is optional but requires you to run lunzip from the directory you compiled it in
cd ..
```

If no errors occurred you should now be able to unzip your files using the command:

```
lunzip <filename>
```

Or if you chose not to run the install command:

```
./lunzip-1.3/lunzip <filename>
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't have the developer tools installed the appropriate way to install them is with:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum groupinstall "Development Libraries"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is progress. When I try the first `make`, I get `cc  -W -O2 -c -o carg_parser.o carg_parser.c
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [carg_parser.o] Error 127`

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Great! I got it to work without the install. The install seems to have failed though. Do I need to do something else to make it install so I can use the `lunzip` command? Although `man lunzip` works, `lunzip <filename>` does not. When I ran `make install`, it output "if [ ! -d "/usr/local/bin" ] ; then install -d -m 755 "/usr/local/bin" ; fi
install -p -m 755 ./lunzip `/usr/local/bin/lunzip"
if [ ! -d "/usr/local/share/man/man1" ] ; then install -d -m 755 "/usr/local/share/man/man1" ; fi`

Comment: You'll need to prepend the full path to so it looks something like: /home/user/lunzip-1.3/lunzip

Comment: shouldn't I be able to install it so i can just type `lunzip <filename>` like any other command?

Comment: You need to be root to install, changed the commands in the answer to reflect this.

Comment: If you want to invoke `lunzip` directly after `(sudo) make install`, you probably need to do a `rehash` in order to update shell's hash table with the new executables.

Comment: @mpy this would only be the case if you have executed the command already and the shell contains a reference to lunzip, which is not the case here.

Comment: I think that depends on the shell. At least with `(t)csh` you should get a `command not found` error without `rehash`. But `bash` and friends populate the hash table automatically, you are right.

Comment: @mpy In the case of (t)csh it isn't automatically indexed indeed.